# is there any function in firebase Google Auth package for flutter to find the date of the creation of user?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

i want to get the user creation timestamp, is there any way to do this?
im using google sign in auth.
 Any help is appreciated!

Edit: i cant find the user creation timestamp when printing the whole user

Edit 2:  Code I am using for authentication:

```
  GoogleSignInAccount currentUser;


final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> signIn() async {
  GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  GoogleSignInAuthentication gSA = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
  FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithGoogle(
      idToken: gSA.idToken, accessToken: gSA.accessToken);

  print('Signed In as ${user.displayName}');
  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the creation timestamp in epoch format with:

```
user.metadata.creationTime
```

See:
[metadata](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/UserMetadata-class.html)

Comment: i am not able to get the metadeta from the user.
please see the updated post, i have added the code. The user i'm returning doesnt provide me the metadeta. It only provides username, email, photourl and id.

Comment: The `metadata` property was introduced in the past few months, so be sure to use the latest `firebase_auth` library.

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen ,  you were right, i was not using the latest version. it works now.

Comment: it has changed. The new way to get it is: ```result.user!.metadata.creationTime;```